# Putting String into database using mySql

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller

I have created an MVC and made a post function so the user can submit text and it will appear right below.

I want to save the text and make another post above it, every time the user submits text, so i created a database called tweettable with 1 varchar attribute called tekst

In my repository i have this create method to put info into the table:

```
@Override
public void create(String tweet) {

    jdbc.update("INSERT INTO tweets.tweettable(tekst) " + "VALUES('" + tweet 
+ "') ");
}
```

This is the code i have for posting in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adminPage(@RequestParam("tweet") String input, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("theText", input);

    userService.create(input);

    return "adminPage";
        }
```

This wont work, when i submit i get the whitelabel error page. It worked before i tried to put a Database on it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not `jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO tweets.tweettable(tekst) VALUES(?)", tweet);`

Comment: Is that a more right way to do it? It still doesn't work

Comment: put your code between try and catch to see the correct problem

Comment: It's a NullPointerException. It actually works now that i got it in a try catch, but thats because it never gets into the try block.

Comment: I chcked if input was == null and its not, so i don't understand why i get this exception.